# C: Passing a char* to a %s in a printf statement

Tags: c, string, pointers, memory-address

I'm studying for a midterm and am having some trouble understanding a concept. Here's the question:

What is the output of the following lines of code:

```
char S1[50] = "jack", S2[50] = "jill", S3[50], *Sptr;

printf("%c$s\n", toupper(S1[0]), &S1[1]);
```

The output is

```
Jack
```

I don't understand, why it's printing  "Jack". %s is supposed to print a string, right? Is &S1[1] a string? I thought it was the address of S1[1]. Is that not the case?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I believe you meant `%c%s\n`. Is this typo in your original code?

Comment: The argument to `%s` is a pointer to the first character of a string.  The address of S1[1] is exactly that.

Answer (score 4):

`printf("%c%s\n", toupper(S1[0]), &S1[1]);`

Let's break that down

`%c` and the corresponding `S1[0]` print the uppercased first character of S1. (J)

`%s` and corresponding `&S1[1]` prints the remainder of the string. (ack)

`&S1[1]` is passing the memory address of the second character of the string.

Answer (score 3):

&S1[1] is an address, which points to 'a' of 'jack'. so %s means to show a string from 'a'  of 'jack' to the end. usually '\0' is the end of a string. that means '%s' prints 'ack' of 'jack'. '%c' prints one character, that is J. toupper()  just changes one character.

Comment: `'\0'` is always the end of a string. That's the definition of "string"